# AttributeError: module 'torch.nn' has no attribute 'ReflectionPad3d'

Tags: python, pytorch

I am practicing on [padding layers](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#padding-layers) in PyTorch.

[1d](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.ReflectionPad1d.html#torch.nn.ReflectionPad1d) and [2d](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.ReflectionPad2d.html#torch.nn.ReflectionPad2d) reflection padding works well.

When I try to run the example given in [3d](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.nn.ReflectionPad3d.html#torch.nn.ReflectionPad3d) padding, the error, given in the title, happened.

```
m = nn.ReflectionPad3d(1)
input = torch.arange(8, dtype=torch.float).reshape(1, 1, 2, 2, 2)
m(input)
```

What can be the reason for this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no `ReflectionPad3d` in the official release yet. The  Documentation you are referring to is addressed to the unstable developer preview. Have a look at the [padding layers section of the newest stable version 1.9.0](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.9.0/nn.html#padding-layers) to see which are the usable layers. Since the official [issue](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/27655) on that topic is already closed, i am sure that it will make its way into the next release.